# Spring Boot : How to pass errors through JSON response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a very basic OpenWeathermap app made with Spring Boot, and when city is not found, OpenWeathermap returns `{"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}`, but I can't pass this from backend to my frontend as JSON. My frontend response is just `Error: Request failed with status code 500`.

I'm handling the responses from backend to frontend as JSON object and parsing the weather data at front.

My `Controller` looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/backend")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/{CITY}")
    public @ResponseBody Object getWeather(@PathVariable String CITY) {

        Object response = WeatherAPI.getCity(CITY);
        return response;
    }
```

and my `WeatherAPI` class looks like this

```
public class WeatherAPI {

    public static Object getCity(String CITY) {

        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = template.getForEntity("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "&units=metric&lang=fi&appid=" + API-KEY-HERE, Object.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I tried for example this: https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-error-handling-example/ and modified my code like this:

`return response.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException());`, but it says `.orElseThrow is undefined for the type`

How can I pass the "city not found" error with the right status code to my frontend?

Comment: You should not mix `@RestController`, `@ResponseBody` and `ResponseEntity<Object>`. 

`@RestController` implies `@ResponseBody` on all REST endpoint in the class.
`@ResponseBody` and `ResponseEntity<Object>` are mutually exclusive and both should not used at the same time.

I would suggest to check an exception is thrown from the controller method. If not, then remove `@RestController` and `@ResponseBody` both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestTemplate will throw an exception for any error responses. You can surround the `template.getForEntity` call in a try-catch block and handle the exceptions, returning the message in any format you want.

The exception you are looking for is `HttpStatusCodeException`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use general error handlers such as [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html), which can handle some specific types of exceptions.

With this mechanism in mind we could adapt your code in the following way:

1. Exceptions from the weather API will be caught and treated in the defined controller advice
2. Your service will throw a custom exception for this use case
3. The `ControllerAdvice` will know which error code to send back to the client.

Some minimal configurations would be:

1. Adding the controllerAdvice to the spring mvc framework, so that when no data for a city is found, your can return the 404 code back

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    /** Provides handling for exceptions throughout this service. */
    @ExceptionHandler({ CityWeatherNotFountException.class })
    @ResponseCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public final ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
```

2. Adapt your service implementation so that it respects the following:

```
public class WeatherAPI {

    public static Object getCity(String CITY) {

        try{

       RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = template.getForEntity("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "&units=metric&lang=fi&appid=" + API-KEY-HERE, Object.class);
        return response;}

     catch(RestException ex){
        throw new CityWeatherNotFountException(ex);}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a General Custom -> RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler to handle client specific and server specific errors, while invoking the RestTemplate calls.

Ref : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling for an example using Spring boot and Spring 5 similar use case.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you should try to understand @RestController implementation. This annotation includes the @Controller and @ResponseBody annotations which simplify controller implementation ([more info here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller)).

Secondly, you can't use the orElseThrow because it is method introduced under the Optional class ([more info here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/optional-orelsethrow-method-in-java-with-examples/)). You given example doesn't use any Optional object.
I think you should study properly on the examples (test it out) provided from the mkyong link. Your given example is too far off from the mkyong examples.

For your actual question, you can change your code as below:
You can use HttpServletResponse class to return your desired status and error message.
You doesn't need to put @ResponseBody as @RestController will automatically do it for you.

```
    @RestController()
    @RequestMapping("/backend")
    public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/{city}")
    public ResponseObject getWeather(@PathVariable String city, HttpServletResponse response) {

        ResponseObject response = WeatherAPI.getCity(city);

        if (response == null) {
            return response.sendError(HttpStatus.PAGE_NOT_FOUND.value(), "message here");
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Lastly, I'm not sure why you using static method for you example. You should create a service layer using @Service for your WeatherAPI.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Update `Controller` to this :

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/backend")
   public class Controller {

        @GetMapping("/{CITY}")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> getWeather(@PathVariable String CITY) {
            Object response = WeatherAPI.getCity(CITY);
            if(response == null) {
               return new ResponseEntity<Object>("city not found", HttpStatus.PAGE_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

   }
```

Update `WeatherAPI` to this :

```
public class WeatherAPI {

    public static Object getCity(String CITY) {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        Object response = template.getForEntity("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "&units=metric&lang=fi&appid=" + API-KEY-HERE, Object.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

This should work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I really appreciate it, and I love to study how all this code work. I must further dive into Spring Boot documentation, do some tutorials, and further study this topic. I tried some of the answers, but they actually did not work.

This is how I solved the problem:

```
        try {
            ResponseEntity<Object> response = template.getForEntity("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/" + QUERY
                    + "?q=" + CITY + "&units=metric&lang=fi&appid=" + API_KEY, Object.class);
            return response;
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException exception) {
            return exception.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }
```

Statement: `return exception.getResponseBodyAsString();` returned the error response to my frontend which I could parse with JavaScript, save into array and such and present to the user.

I would still like to learn how to catch more errors and bring them to frontend, so I could build an "admin panel" to see and log everything that happens at backend. I'm really keen to learn Java and Spring Boot framework.

I wrote some JavaScript to my frontend to prevent empty inputs or search queries that provoke errors from my backend, since I can't yet properly deal with them. I also have some redirecting going on at the backend, so that errors wont break any functionality.

Thank you all once again for the kind support and detailed descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use ResponseEntity

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/backend")
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/{CITY}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> Object getWeather(@PathVariable String CITY) {

        Object response = WeatherAPI.getCity(CITY);
        if (response != null) {
         return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
          return new ResponseEntity<String>("City Not Found", HttpStatus.Not_Found);
       }
    }
```

ResponseEntity will alse return the status code like 200 for success 404 for not found etc and it will bind to your response

Comment: I really like how this shows the response, but only "200" is coming through, 404 is catched by Spring Boot at the backend and gives "Error 500" at the frontend. So only 200 is working with this implementation, yet I would really like to get all the errors codes, 404 etc. :(

Comment: You can get every error code according to your need. You can pass the enum like OK, NOT_FOUND etc (eclipse will provide enum suggestion). There are many more enums except OK, NOT_FOUND and each of them having separate status code